# Как правильно загружать npm-пакет без файлов production версии в репозитории?

Tags: node.js, git, webpack, npm, package

Есть npm-пакет, production-версия которого собирается с помощью webpack в папку `./build`. Соответственно в `package.json` прописано `"main": "build/index.js"`. Но в репозиторий на GitHub папку build класть не нужно она находится в `.gitignore`.
Вопрос: как правильно автоматически загружать пакет на npm при этом не загружая production сборку в репозиторий?

Comment: Очевидно собирать перез загрузкой в npm. Для этого есть prepublish https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#use-cases

Comment: выставлено `"prepublish": "yarn run lint && yarn run test && yarn run build"` все равно не загружается если есть build в .gitignore

Comment: Можно использовать массив files в package.json. Или создать .npmignore

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files